# Redirect you too many times. Try clearing your cookies. ERR_TO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: dns, github-pages, namecheap

I am using Namecheap registrar and hosting my website using Github pages. I've followed the Namecheap instructions to setup a URL redirect. But sometimes the website does not load up because of the above mentioned issue.

My Advanced DNS records on Namecheap are [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Usuq.jpg)

Is there anything wrong with my records?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this a few minutes ago, myself. For me, the issue was my .htaccess file. There's a line starting with "DirectoryIndex", which defines the file name that the webserver is going to look for when someone goes to your domain. Check the extension of the file name and make sure it matches your index file. Mine was .php and I needed it to be .html.